# SaveFileDialog Overwrite Prompt Not On Top

Tags: c#, user-experience, savefiledialog

I am encountering a minor UX issue with `SaveFileDialog.OverWritePrompt` in my C# Windows Form Application. When I elect to overwrite a file, the prompt should appear on top, but it does not. The prompt is being created, though. In order to get it to appear on top, I have to press the Alt key. Here is my code. I hope that you can reproduce my error.

```
private void ExportImage_Option_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Main_PictureBox.Image != null)
    {
        SaveFileDialog SFD = new SaveFileDialog(this);
        SFD.Filter = "Image Files (*.bmp, *.jpg, *.png)|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.png";
        SFD.OverwritePrompt = true;
        DialogResult Result = SFD.ShowDialog(this);
        if (Result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.Main_PictureBox.Image.Save(SFD.FileName);
        }
    }
    else {
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing to export.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try to call `SFD.ShowDialog(this)` instead of `SFD.ShowDialog()`?

Comment: Done! The problem still persists, unfortunately.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot reproduce this error. The prompt pops up on top of all windows.

Comment: @MongZhu: Thanks. I kind of figured that this might be specific to my computer. I'll keep an eye on responses to this question, and also check my settings.

Comment: What OS is this running on? And this is called from a normal button click? And on the UI-thread, not from a background worker or so?

Comment: Try to remove this `SFD.OverwritePrompt = true;` and check again

Comment: @rene: This is on Windows 10 Pro. This happens when called from 1) button click, 2) context menu, 3) menu item in menu bar, 4) key press event.

Comment: @Fourat: Thanks for the advice. Tried, but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the SFD owner:

```
DialogResult Result = SFD.ShowDialog(this);
```

From MSDN:

> This version of the ShowDialog method allows you to specify a specific
>   form or control that will own the dialog box that is shown. If you use
>   the version of this method that has no parameters, the dialog box
>   being shown would be owned automatically by the currently active
>   window of your application.

More details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a55b9ds(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your input is well taken, and I have implemented it. However, the original issue still persists. I will update the original query to reflect this edit.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be specific to my computer, since no one else can reproduce the issue. This does not have to do with the code, but is more likely related to my system settings.

Comment: It is not! I'm experiencing that behaviour too!
The coolest thing is, to bring it to the top, I just need to press Alt!

Comment: The problem was gone!
The difference that I did was change DefaultExt, remove the initial dot!
Ex.: DefaultExt=".TXT" to DefaultExt="TXT"
Yes, seems crazy, but the problem is gone!